# Friendica integration using wordpress authentication

Tags: customization, authentication, single-sign-on

I currently have a BuddyPress community with bbPress forums and a MediaWiki based collaborative area.

I'll soon be adding [Friendica](http://friendica.com/) support for good integration with other friends [Diaspora](http://diasporaproject.org/) websites plus other social network integration that Friendica can provide.

I basically want Friendica to use BuddyPress for authentication, single sign on.  If the user is logged in on BuddyPress, they are logged in on Friendica.

I may have to develop this from scratch, in which case I document what I do and post it as an answer here, but before I do that, if anyone has already done this and can post instructions on how to do it, that would be a big help.

Comment: [BuddyPrees/Facebook Authentication](http://buddydev.com/buddypress/introducing-buddypress-facebook-connect-advance-facebook-loginregistration-plugin-for-your-buddypress-based-social-network/)

Comment: @fdsa I don't think that would work as its the wrong way around.  Besides a lot of my members, including myself, don't have facebook accounts.  Nor do we want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I think this needs to be done:

1. Examine how an existing integration allows a particular CMS to authenticate using wordpress.  Possibly [this MediaWiki integration](http://insites.ingenesis.net/2008/08/17/wordpress-bbpress-mediawiki/).   Work out how this authenticates a wordpress user.
2. Examine an existing friendica authentication plugin, such as [the LDAP one that comes with the CMS](http://friendica.com/extend), and update this to use the wordpress authentication method calculated in step 1.

*(If no-one beats me to a more complete answer, I will add more detail as I work through this.  Otherwise I hope this partial answer will inspire a more complete answer).*